# Tomcat blankpage for default error page

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-404

First off, I'm using Tomcat 5.5 and my .jsp's live in /webapps/foo/bar/*.jsp.

I followed the directions  [here](http://linux-sxs.org/internet_serving/c581.html)  to set up a default 404 error page. In my TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml I entered:

```
    <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.html</location>
    </error-page>
```

I dropped copies of a test error.html file into each of the dirs (I wasn't sure where /error.html was referring to):

```
/webapps/
/webapps/foo/
/webapps/foo/bar/
```

Whenever I attempt to access a non-existent page in a browser at url's  /foo/missingpage.html or /foo/bar/missingpage.html I'm redirected to my error page that exists in /foo/error.html.

However, attempting to access a non-existent page in a browser at url /missingpage.html yields a blankpage. Or any permutation of /missingDir/missingfile.html will also yield a blank page. Any suggestions? Am I missing some extra configuration?

Thanks

PR

Comment: Anything in page source? (browser > rightclick > view source). Anything in server logs? (check tomcat/logs folder).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try putting `error.html` in `/webapps/ROOT/`. This will work if your Tomcat worker is handling all URL requests (*yourdomain.com/anything*).